# ajax url call confusion

Tags: php, jquery

EDIT:
I will try to explain what I want to do a bit better. I am displaying a table with all the fields retrieved from a database using an ajax call to a php file (eg. other.php) in my main.php. What I am trying to figure out is once the table is displayed to screen and the call is in the other.php file, can I implement an update query within other.php to update a field in the database with a user input? Does that make sense? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "Once in that php file"? You send the AJAX request after clicking an option, and the server processes your PHP to return a response (a HTML table). Where do the additional tasks fit in?

Comment: my apologies. Let me give some more details. The table displayed has  values already inputted and there are values that need to be filled in by the user (eg. electrical company monthly rates). What I want to find out is how to have the user update the database with those values by pressing an Update button. Does that make sense? Thanks for your super quick response.

Comment: @user1251068 I would suggest rewriting your question to be more clear based on your comment, and add a "PHP" tag to it. Yes, you can get the values out of the HTML table with `$('td#my-id').text()` and send "POST" requests to PHP using `$.post()`, but for more detail you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Assuming that you have a form that the user fills before clicking in the menu, you can add this values in your ajax call.

For example, assuming that you have a search button

```
<input type='text' name='search' id='search' />
```

You can pass this to your php with `get` or `post` (type of request)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "somefile.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: "search=" + $('#search').val(),
  success: function(data){
    //do something...
  }
});
```

And in your `somefile.php` you can access the value with `$_POST['search']` or `$_GET['search']` (depending of the type of the request).

I think with this you can adapt to your reality. More samples you can get in the JQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).